# Realtek High Definition Audio Speakers sounds scratchy when Windows has been running for a few days

Tags: windows, audio, windows-8.1, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

If Windows has been running for a while, then my Realtek High Definition Audio output sounds scratchy and annoying. Rebooting helps, but I don't want to reboot every few days. I've tried disabling the device in Device Manager then re-enabling it, but that doesn't help. I've tried to search for an updated driver, but it says it has the latest driver. The current drivers are:

[image]

[image]

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the drivers but I can't find an update.

I have the following choices:

[image]

I'm not using HDMI on my graphics card. I have regular speakers with a 3.5mm cable. I don't know if there is a HDMI to 3.5mm female jack converter, or a digital audio output to 3.5mm female.

Answer (score 1):

You might see better performance using the drivers obtainable direct from Realtek - they also contain a better 5.1 interface than the drivers Windows keeps insisting on replacing them with.

You need to click through the 'accept' box to get there - [Realtek High Definition Audio Drivers](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)

Alternatively, see if switching output to another device then back again would wake it up. I used [Audio Switcher](https://audioswit.ch/er) (freeware) for many years, though I don't have a Windows machine any more to test whether it's still good.

Comment: !RemindMe 1 week

Comment: It's messing up again. Is there anything else I can do, like get an HDMI to 3.5mm converter or get a different sound card?